# JQuery Validate with Success Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var validator = $("#my-form").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
            $("#errtxt").html("Please correct the errors shown below:");
            $("#errtxt").addClass("error-msg");
        }).validate({
        success: function(label) {
            label.addClass("valid");
        },
        rules: { 
            text1: {
                required: true
            },
            text2: {
                required: true,
            }
        }, 
        messages: { 
            text1: "",
            text2: "",
        } ,
        errorElement: "span"
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post">
    <span class="errtxt"></span>
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I basically want an empty span on error to display an image. However on success the image should change so it should have a different class.
The problem is my span is getting both classes "error" and "valid" whatever I do. But this is only happening because I have empty messages, if I don't have empty messages the classes seem to get applied as required. For example changing it to this works:

```
        messages: { 
            text1: "&nbsp;",
            text2: "&nbsp;",
        } ,
```

However i'd like an empty error span just for my bg image. Is this a bug or something i'm doing wrong, I don't understand the code too much but maybe the way i'm doing this:

success: function(label) {
 label.addClass("valid");
 },

Could be wrong. If I have to keep using an empty space it's no big deal but it seems like a bug.

Also while we are on the subject is there any easy way to default all field messages to a default of "".

---

On submit, I want:
- next to each input an empty span with the class error (if the field is empty)
- or the class valid if it passes (if the field has contents).

The problem is the span is getting both classes "error valid" even when the field is empty. But if I have a error message text in it works, but ideally I don't want any error message text. I think it might be a bug. See the most simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                  
$("#my-form").validate({
        rules: { 
            text1: {
                required: true
            },
        }, 
        messages: { 
            text1: "",
        } ,
        errorElement: "span",
        success: "valid",
    });
});
</script>
<style>
span.error{
    float:left; width:15px; height:15px;
    background:red;
}
span.valid{
    display:block; width:15px; height:15px;
    background:green;
}
</style>
</head>    
<body>
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You will see this doesn't work. But this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                  
$("#my-form").validate({
        rules: { 
            text1: {
                required: true
            },
        }, 
        messages: { 
            text1: "&nbsp;",
        } ,
        errorElement: "span",
        success: "valid",
    });
});
</script>
<style>
span.error{
    float:left; width:15px; height:15px;
    background:red;
}
span.valid{
    display:block; width:15px; height:15px;
    background:green;
}
</style>
</head>    
<body>
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label>
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Only difference is having something in the messages texts!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#my-form").validate({
      rules: {
         text1: {
            required: true
         }
         text2: {
            required: true
         }
      },
      messages: {
         text1: {
            required: "Please fill out text1."
         }
         text2: {
            required: "Please fill out text2."
         }
      },
      errorLabelContainer: ".errtxt",
      success: "valid"
   });
});
```

if this works for you, please select the check mark next to my answer. i am trying to get enough reputation to leave comments. thanks!